# command doesnt work properly when scheduled

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to schedule a bash script which will delete some files in a remote machine.

```
LOCATION=/var/ftp/pub/test/

SCRIPT="cd $LOCATION; rm -rf *.bin*"
output=$(ssh -l $USERNAME $HOST $SCRIPT)

Files in the remote server:

linux_12345.bin
linux_56743.bin.sig
linux_74635.bin
```

When I run the script in a shell it deletes the file properly, but if I schedule it in cron it doesn't delete the files. Even I tried linux_* and it doesn't work. Looks like if it ends with * it doesn't work with scheduling.

But, if I use *.bin, it deletes all the files that ends with .bin even with scheduling.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: The `-r` flag in your `rm` command is not necessary in this situation (unless you're also trying to delete some directories matching the glob `*.bin*`) and is super dangerous (especially when debugging), so I would suggest removing it for safety.

Comment: Path is correct. no luck after changing it to  rm -r.

Comment: please post the relevant line from your crontab

Comment: 00 12 * * * /opt/test/deleteFiles.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote at least `$SCRIPT`, otherwise any .bin files in the current *local* directory will change your command:

```
output=$(ssh -l $USERNAME $HOST "$SCRIPT")
```

The current directory for the script as run by crontab may be different from your current directory when testing it, thus causing different behavior.

(To recreate the problem when you're testing it manually, run `touch foo.bin` before executing `/opt/test/deleteFiles.sh`).

Also make sure you specify the shell you are trying to run the script in. At the beginning of your script, have a line like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This will avoid variances due to different default shell settings.

Comment: This works. Thanks for the suggestion.  Also the script starts with #!/bin/bash.